# Games and ads opening up on phone unexpectedly.

Tags: applications

I have game applications opening at what seems like random or after I let my phone sit idle. I then have to close that tab or close all tabs to get back to the home screen so I can use my phone. I have recently downloaded some apps and I suspect this is the cause. How can I get back to normal and keep these games and adds from opening. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! I'd start with uninstalling those "recently downloaded" apps one by one to figure which of them is causing that. You could also [check the logs](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/logging/info) for hints.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded a  add on detector app for free and it helped pinpoint the app that caused the problem. Thank you again for you help.

Comment: Craig, may I suggest you [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) then – with some more details (which detector you've used, what criteria to find out, what the faulty app was)? Might help others in a similar situation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are various options:

1. Do a factory reset. Go to Settings>Backup & Personal Data-Factory Data Reset
2. Root your phone. Install Xposed. Block Wakeups using either AppsOpsXposed or Permission Master.

Comment: What do wakeups have to do with that? And don't you think a factory-reset is a bit harsh here?

Comment: As @Izzy said, don't you think both of those options are abit extreme and complex for this situation?

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded a  add on detector app for free and it helped pinpoint the app that caused the problem. Thank you again for you help.

Answer (score 0):

If you suspect that a certain application that you downloaded is the cause of this issue, then I would suggest uninstalling the suspect application and seeing if that fixes your problem.